# Create complex objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two classes

```
class GpsPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
validates   :longitude, :presence   =>  true
validates   :latitude,  :presence   =>  true

belongs_to  :station
end
```

and

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name,  :presence =>  true,
                :length => { :maximum  =>  50 }
    validates :gps_point, :presence =>  true

    has_one :gps_point
    belongs_to :route
end
```

The gps points are enter separated from station when a station is created i want to be able select a gps point from a drop down list.

How can i create the dropdown list with all the gps points ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= select('station', 'gps_point_id', GpsPoint.all.collect {|u| [u.name,u.id]}) %>
```

Comment: You also would want to switch around belongs_to and has_one for the two models to follow the logic you're going for...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic). It's a gem that lets you easily create forms and automatically deals with Foreign Keys really well - lets you create a drop down or radio buttons.

Otherwise there is decent article on rails select helpers:

http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails